# I want to set different function on each row generated through jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to apply different function on each new row field with the same name and id generated using jQuery add new row function.

```
    $('body').on("click", "#addrow", function(e) {

    var newRow = $("<tr class='txtMult'>");
    var cols = "";
cols += '<td style="margin-top:15px;line-height:25px">' + counter + '</td>';
cols += '<td><input style="width:150px;margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="ProductName_'+ counter +'" name="ProductName[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnProductName_'+ counter +'" name="ProductId[]"></td>'
cols += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input style="width:95%; margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="LocationName_'+ counter +'" name="LocationName_[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnLocationName_'+ counter +'" name="LocationId[]"></td>';
cols += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input style="width:95%; margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="ColourName_'+ counter +'" name="ColourName[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnColourName_'+ counter +'" name="ColourId[]"></td>';
cols += '<td><input style="width:90%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Rate'+ counter +'" class="Rate" name="Rate[]" autocomplete="off"></td>';
cols += '<td><input style="width:65%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Quantity'+ counter +'" class="Quantity" name="Quantity[]" autocomplete="off"></td>';
cols += '<td><input style="width:90%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Amount'+ counter +'" class="Amount" name="Amount[]"></td>';
cols += '<td style="width:70px;text-align:right; cursor:pointer; color:red;"><i class="icon icon-trash remove" title="Delete" style="margin-top:1px;"></i></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});
```

I want this function to be called each time based on the ProductId generated from jQuery. But it's working only on first row, not others.

```
            $('body').on('change', 'input[id^=LocationName]', function(){
            var ProductId = $('[name=ProductId]').val();
            var LocationId = $('[name=LocationId]').val();

            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'html',
               data: ('LocationId='+LocationId+'&ProductId='+ProductId),
               url: "<?php echo base_url('Sales/GetRemainingProduct'); ?>",
               success: function(response){
                $('#RemainingStock').html(response);
               }
            });
        });
```

Everything is fine but the function is being called based on first id of first row.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your selector of productId and locationId, they are taking the first element they find in the html, no matter with element was changed. For location you can use:

```
$(this).val()
```

To get the element that was changed.And for the product you can take the parent and then the children asociated with this location:

```
 $(this).parent().find('[name=LocationId]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem :

1. You want to send server request each time on product name textbox change
2. It is working for first time only

> Solution :
>
> 1. Firstly you need to complete `</tr>` tag in dynamically added row.
> 2. Secondly, you are need two textbox attribute as below  :
>
>    1. `ProductId` from ProductName_1, 2, 3 etc.
>    2. `LocationId` from hdnLocationName__1, 2, 3 etc.
> 3. You need to declare a `counter` variable in javascript to show row index.

Please check below code :

```js
var counter = 1;
$('body').on("click", "#addrow", function (e) {

    var newRow = $("<tr class='txtMult'>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td style="margin-top:15px;line-height:25px">' + counter + '</td>';
    cols += '<td><input style="width:150px;margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="ProductName_' + counter + '" name="ProductName[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnProductName_' + counter + '" name="ProductId[]"></td>'
    cols += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input style="width:95%; margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="LocationName_' + counter + '" name="LocationName_[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnLocationName_' + counter + '" name="LocationId[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input style="width:95%; margin-top:1px;" class="select2" type="text" id="ColourName_' + counter + '" name="ColourName[]"><input style="width:90%;" type="hidden" id="hdnColourName_' + counter + '" name="ColourId[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input style="width:90%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Rate' + counter + '" class="Rate" name="Rate[]" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input style="width:65%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Quantity' + counter + '" class="Quantity" name="Quantity[]" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input style="width:90%; margin-top:1px; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Amount' + counter + '" class="Amount" name="Amount[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td style="width:70px;text-align:right; cursor:pointer; color:red;"><i class="icon icon-trash remove" title="Delete" style="margin-top:1px;"></i></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    newRow.append('</tr>');
    $(".table").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});

$('body').on('change', 'input[id^=LocationName]', function () {
    var ProductId = $(this).attr('name');
    var LocationId = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[id^=hdnLocationName]').attr('name');

    console.log('Goint to server for ProductId : ' + ProductId + ', LocationId : ' + LocationId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: ('LocationId=' + LocationId + '&ProductId=' + ProductId),
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Sales/GetRemainingProduct'); ?>",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#RemainingStock').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addrow">Add New Row</button>

<table class="table"></table>
```

Comment: its generating two rows while click on add row and Goint to server for ProductId : undefined message in console

Comment: @SarmadSoomro, as you can see that `name="ProductId[]"` and `name="LocationId[]"` both are hard coded in the code, so that will be `undefined` for now, You need to apply that logic as per your requirement.